# send data to one fragment to other fragment in viewpager

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment, viewpage, adaptor

I am using  3 fragment in viewpager and try to communicate between all fragments(send data)

> I am using  3 fragment in viewpager and try to communicate between all fragments(send data)

Comment: please past your viewpager adapter code hear

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of different ways to share data between fragments, I like using a shared view model, the different ways are outlined in https://androidwave.com/passing-data-between-fragments/